# Building SOA composite application using maven

Tags: maven, ant, soa, osb

Using SOA suite 11, trying building source code (composite.xml with configuration file) in SOA composite application into a jar file using maven.

Can anyone help to guide me making POM.xml for the same. i am using "Apache-ANT-Plugin" in my pom file.

Answer (score 0):

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         
           This POM relates to this SOA Composite, i.e. the one in this same directory.
           There is another POM in the SOA Application directory which handles
           the whole SOA Application, which may contain additional projects. 
        -->
    4.0.0
    test1
    HelloWrold
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    sar

```
<!--
       The parent points to the common SOA parent POM.  That is a special POM that is
       shipped by Oracle as a point of customization (only). You can add default values
       for properties like serverUrl, etc. to the SOA common parent POM, so that you
       do not have to specify them over and over in every project POM.
--> 
<parent>
    <groupId>com.oracle.soa</groupId>
    <artifactId>sar-common</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <!-- These parameters are used by the compile goal -->
    <scac.input.dir>${project.basedir}\SOA/</scac.input.dir>
    <scac.output.dir>${project.basedir}/target</scac.output.dir>
    <scac.input>${scac.input.dir}/composite.xml</scac.input>
    <scac.output>${scac.output.dir}/out.xml</scac.output>
    <scac.error>${scac.output.dir}/error.txt</scac.error>
    <scac.displayLevel>1</scac.displayLevel>
    <!-- if you are using a config plan, uncomment the following line and update to point
         to your config plan -->
    <!--<configplan>${scac.input.dir}/configplan.xml</configplan>-->

    <!-- These parameters are used by the deploy and undeploy goals --> 
    <composite.name>${project.artifactId}</composite.name>
    <composite.revision>1.0</composite.revision>
    <composite.partition>default</composite.partition>        
    <serverUrl>${oracleServerUrl}</serverUrl>        
    <user>${oracleUsername}</user>
    <password>${oraclePassword}</password>
    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
    <forceDefault>true</forceDefault>
    <regenerateRulebase>false</regenerateRulebase>
    <keepInstancesOnRedeploy>false</keepInstancesOnRedeploy>

    <!-- These parameters are used by the test goal 
     if you are using the sca-test (test) goal, you need to uncomment the following
         line and point it to your jndi.properties file. --> 

    <!--<jndi.properties.input>UNDEFINED</jndi.properties.input>-->
    <scatest.result>${scac.output.dir}/testResult</scatest.result>
    <!--  input is the name of the composite to run test suties against -->
    <input>${project.artifactId}</input>

    <!--<scac.ant.buildfile>${env.MW_HOME}/soa/bin/ant-sca-compile.xml</scac.ant.buildfile>
    <sca.ant.testfile>${env.MW_HOME}/soa/bin/ant-sca-test.xml</sca.ant.testfile>
    -->

</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.oracle.soa.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle-soa-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compositeName>${project.artifactId}</compositeName>
                <composite>${scac.input}</composite>
                <sarLocation>${scac.output.dir}/sca_${project.artifactId}_rev${composite.revision}.jar</sarLocation>
                <serverUrl>${serverUrl}</serverUrl>
                <user>${user}</user>
                <password>${password}</password>
                <!-- Note: compositeRevision is needed to package, revision is needed to undeploy -->
                <compositeRevision>${composite.revision}</compositeRevision>
                <revision>${composite.revision}</revision>
                <scacInputDir>${scac.input.dir}</scacInputDir>                    
                <input>${input}</input> 
            </configuration>
             <!-- extensions=true is needed to use the custom sar packaging type -->
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: please use the above POM file in the BPEL project